# Issues with fullscreen Bootstrap carousel plugin in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, firefox

So I'm still fairly new to jQuery and javascript, so I've tried to mess around with the code to fix my issues when the plugin runs in Firefox. No dice, so I'm coming here for some advice (and perhaps an explanation as to why the following issue occurred).

The problem here is that I have some other Divs, below the one containing the carousel. In Firefox, it ends up replacing all of my other image and color backgrounds with transparency, revealing the carousel behind all my content.

Heres the code for the plugin:

```
$('.header-carousel').carousel({
    pause: "false",
    interval: 4000
});

$('.header-carousel').css({'margin': 0, 'width': $(window).outerWidth(), 'height': $(window).outerHeight()});
$('.header-carousel .item').css({'position': 'fixed', 'width': '100%', 'height': '100%'});
$('.carousel-inner div.item img').each(function() {
    var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).parent().css({'background': 'url('+imgSrc+') center center no-repeat', '-webkit-background-size': '100% ', '-moz-background-size': '100%', '-o-background-size': '100%', 'background-size': '100%', '-webkit-background-size': 'cover', '-moz-background-size': 'cover', '-o-background-size': 'cover', 'background-size': 'cover'});
    $(this).remove();
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    $('.header-carousel').css({'width': $(window).outerWidth(), 'height': $(window).outerHeight()});
});
```

Hope I was able to explain this effectively, I've been struggling with this issue for days now...

---

EDIT:

I made an example on jsfiddle. What would be the best way to force the carousel to not stay fixed to the background when scrolling?

https://jsfiddle.net/pavelcreates/8nxwzgjz/

Comment: I suggest you either post your code in a JS Fiddle or provide your HTML and CSS so people can better help you.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the problem by adding a z-index rule:

```
.header-carousel { z-index: -101; }
```

Bootstrap's carousel likes to throw their images at  `z-index: -100;`, so throwing the full-screen carousel behind it fixes all the issues of my previously missing background images and colours.